# How to get feeds for specific channels by passing channel ids in youtube v3 search api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As per documentation I am able to retrieve channels that I have subscribed by this way:

```
GET {base_URL}/subscriptions?part=snippet
                            &mine=true
```

now I need to fetch the feeds of particular channel or in bunch so I need something like this

```
GET {base_URL}/search?part=snippet
                     &channelIds = {CHANEL_IDS}                  
                     &type=video
                     &videoCaption=closedCaption
                     &key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

gives me the feeds of provided channel ids. I prefer to use v3 api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do though [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails
              &id={CHANEL_IDS}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```